# Updated code is not reflecting in browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I have created one IMS System in that i have modified table layout code in notepad++ it saved properly but in browser (firefox/chrome) still old code is coming.If Anybody Know solution than please help.
NodePad++ Code

```
<td style="width:136px">Product Name</td>
      <td class="hsn">HSN/SAC</td>
      <td style="width:65px">Rate</td>
      <td style="width:63px">Qty</td>
      <td style="width:93px">Unit</td>  
      <td style="width:71px">Gross<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:42px">CGST<br>(%)</td>
      <td style="width:65px">CGST<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:42px">SGST<br>(%)</td>
      <td style="width:54px">SGST<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:54px">Tax<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:67px">Net<br>Amount</td>
```

Browser Code

```
<td style="width:100px">Product Name</td>
      <td class="hsn">HSN/SAC</td>
      <td style="width:49px">Rate</td>
      <td style="width:51px">Qty</td>
      <td style="width:62px">Unit</td>
      <td style="width:69px">Gross<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:47px">CGST<br>(%)</td>
      <td style="width:63px">CGST<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:47px">SGST<br>(%)</td>
      <td style="width:58px">SGST<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:56px">Tax<br>Amount</td>
      <td style="width:67px">Net<br>Amount</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a browser caching issue.  That is, the browser thinks it is doing you a favor by using old content which it cached, to avoid an unnecessary page refresh.  From Google's documentation on clearing the cache in Chrome:

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More More.
- Click More tools and then Clear browsing data.
- At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select All time.
- Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the boxes.
- Click Clear data.

The only thing you should in fact have to remove are the cached images and files.  Do that, then reload the page, and the problem should be fixed.

Follow [this link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for more information.